# VBA - Identifying subs and functions called from other subs/procedures

Tags: vba, excel

Struggling to come up with a title for this one. I have a project which contains around 20 forms / 10 code & class modules. This project has multiple functions which fit together nicely to solve specific purposes, but can also be segmented to satisfy similar needs in other projects. Those other projects may not necessarily need the other components.

An example of this may be: One part of the project can create a powerpoint, while another part of the project may be able to send emails. This project uses both, however another project may only need one of those functions.

I have tried my best to separate these functions into their self contained modules. However, I have placed functions that are commonly used in a separate module ("All") so that I am able to utilize the same code without repeating in various places. I am self-taught so if this isn't a best practice, let me know.

The issue is that I now want to be able to export certain modules from one project to the other. I am building a tool which will let me distribute these modules as fully functional packages that will work without any setup on the destination file. In order to accomplish this, I need to understand where my subs/functions are pointing. How interconnected are my modules? If I exported, lets say the PowerPoint module, does that module try and access something in my "All" module? If that's the case, I would need to also export any relevant code from that module to the new workbook.

If the first tier of procedures are the ones listed in the target module, then the second tier of procedures would be the ones called via the T1 procedures. This means that T3 procedures are called from T2 procedures and so on...

How would I write a Loop function that needs to go deeper and deeper? The exit condition is most certainly when all T1 procedures have been fully explored.

The below code simply gets me a list of procedures in the target module and adds them to an array.

```
Sub getProcs()

Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim VBMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim lineNum As Integer
Dim lineText As String
Dim lineCount As Integer
Dim procArr As Variant
Dim procName As String
Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind

'Set Target Objects
Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(2)
Set VBMod = VBComp.CodeModule
With VBMod
    If .CountOfLines > 0 Then
        lineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
        Do Until lineNum >= .CountOfLines
            procName = .ProcOfLine(lineNum, ProcKind)
            procArr = all_dataArray(procArr, procName)
            lineNum = .ProcStartLine(procName, ProcKind) + _
                    .ProcCountLines(procName, ProcKind) + 1
        Loop
    End If
End With
End Sub

Function all_dataArray(arr As Variant, arrVal As Variant) As Variant
'Add item to array
If IsEmpty(arr) Or Not IsArray(arr) Then
    arr = Array(arrVal)
Else
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr)) = arrVal
End If
all_dataArray = arr
End Function
```

Perhaps I am going about this all wrong, happy to hear any advice.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I believe getProcs isn't getting anything because VBComp is setting to your VBComponent(2), which may not mean anything to your current workbook. Would suggest you change "2" with the name of an actual component with a codemodule.

I see what you're saying about the lexer. Perhaps I should be moving towards fully self contained modules.

Comment: I haven't executed your code. I mean everything in `getProcs` is local, and it's a `Sub` procedure, therefore whatever it does, dies at `End Sub`. "GetSomething" should be a function that returns something. `all_dataArray` is assigning its `arr` byref argument, which points to the very same array pointer being assigned at the call site - which is extremely unsettling. Regardless, sorry to say, your efforts are doomed. You will not be able to parse VBA code with procedural VBA code. We're 4 years into an actual parser with a grammar written against the language specs, and still hit edge cases.

Comment: I think we're getting caught up on the naming of a simple example sub. The point of it is to add all procs to the procArr, which it does. You are correct in that it probably isn't worth my time.

Comment: I find myself questioning the logic of automating code reuse by copy and paste.  Just put all the common code in an add-in and reference it.

Comment: Hey Comintern. I actually do that exactly for code used solely by myself. This project is coming from a place where I want to create a "self-contained" project that can be sent around without the need to install an add-in on each computer.

Comment: Fair enough.  If they're already in common modules, I'm confused as to why you're trying to parse your own code. I'd just use the `VBComponent.Export` and `VBComponent.Import` functions instead. Whatever you do, be careful of naming collisions...

Comment: Gosh, I completely missed the `all_dataArray = arr` assignment at the very bottom. Ignore my above comments about `all_dataArray` returning `Empty`.

Comment: "Call Stack" is built-in the VBA IDE without any code needed. youtube.com/watch?v=x6-tdmYNKCw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying the members/procedures of a module is only one step, and it's as far as the VBIDE API is going to be helpful.

The next step is to determine where the procedure calls are, and in order to successfully do this, you need to take the text of the module, and *somehow* determine what's a procedure call, and which procedure is being called: in order to reliably do this, you're going to need to "programmatically understand" the VBA code as well as VBA itself.

The only way to do this, is to turn the text into a stream of *tokens* (that's what a *lexer* does), turn that stream of tokens into a tree structure (that's what a *parser* does), then traverse these trees and populate a *symbol table* that contains information about what's declared in what scope and which scopes can "see" it. Then you need to traverse the parse trees again, locate the nodes representing procedure calls, find the name in your symbol table, and *resolve* the identifier reference to a specific symbol, in accordance with VBA's language scoping rules.

The *tokenizing* step needs to take into account pesky annoying things like comments, line continuations, and precompiler directives.

Once you've resolved identifier references, all you need to do is iterate the references to each procedure in your symbol table, and list their respective parent scope/procedure - then you know who's calling who.

I cannot think of any other reliable way to do this... and I can't imagine doing this in VBA. [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s parser is somewhere in the ballpark of 45,000 lines of C# code, *generated* by processing an Antlr4 grammar designed to VBA's language specifications. And that's not even the preprocessor and resolver parts, which have their very own challenges and complexities.

---

That said no, an "All" module isn't best practice. In fact it's a sure-shot way to get a dumping bag of whatever: if a module (or class) is a `FooUtils`, a `FooManager`, a `FooHelper`, or any other such vaguely-scoped loose term that basically stands for "whatever stuff I couldn't fit anywhere else", something is wrong with the design.

I don't know what your "commonly used" functions are, but it's likely that what you need is just further modularization. Extract these helper methods into more specialized modules/classes - a `ListObjectExtensions` module clearly states what's in scope for it, so you shouldn't expect to find e.g. a `Get1DArrayFromRange` function in there.

Comment: Mathieu, appreciate your response. I believe you have understood my question fully and have answered it. It also seems you are much further along the path to answering what seems to be a very comprehensive task. It's unfortunate that there isn't a clear way of doing it. Mostly because of VBA support. I will check out your project and see if it will help me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it in the past but with no perfect results. It helped me to get an incomplete (or sometimes overloaded) list of dependencies and for the rest let the compiler complain to fix...

Also huge effort - rarely need it. In fact if you are doing good job in programming you try to split every function to small independed functions. So finally when you ask for dependecies of a single function, it turn outs that the answer is usuall almost your entire project!

This code is a whole module with references to custom general functions of other modules, for extracting token lists, concatanating arrays etc.

Any way I post some **abstracts** of functions I used. I don't know if could be helpfull.

Good luck!

1.

```
Function GetComponentProcDependences(Optional ComponentName As String = "Module1", Optional ProjectName As String = "")
[...]
objProject = VBAEditor.VBProjects.item(ProjectName)
[...]
PutativeDependences = Quicksort(ProjectFunctionList(objProject, False, False), True)
[...]
allreadyincluded = ComponentMethodsList(ReferencesComponent, False, False)
[...]
For Each item In allreadyincluded 
Call FindProcDependences(CStr(item), ProjectName, PutativeDependences, allreadyincluded)
Next
GetComponentProcDependences = allreadyincluded
End Function
```

2.

```
Function ProjectFunctionList(Optional objProject As VBIDE.VBProject = Nothing, Optional Titles As Boolean = True, Optional args As Boolean = True)
[...]
For Each objComponent In objProject.VBComponents
    cs = ComponentMethodsList(objComponent, Titles, args)
[...]
 ProjectFunctionList= ArrayConcatenate(ex, cs)
[...]
End Function
```

3.

```
    Public Function ComponentMethodsList(objComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent, Optional inclTitle As Boolean = True, Optional args As Boolean = True)
    [...]
     Dim objCode As VBIDE.CodeModule
    [...]
    Do While iLine < objCode.CountOfLines
    sProcName = objCode.ProcOfLine(iLine, pk)
    [...]
                    pclc = objCode.ProcCountLines(sProcName, pk)
                    pblc = objCode.ProcBodyLine(sProcName, pk)
    [...]
   pcl = Replace(objCode.Lines(pblc, decllines), " _", "") 'etc
    [...]
     Call AddToListSub(IIf(inclTitle, objComponent.Name & ".", "") & sProcName & 
    IIf(args, "#" & pcl, ""), res)
    [...]
    iLine = iLine + pclc
    [...]
    Loop
    ComponentMethodsList = res
    End Function
```

4.

```
Sub FindProcDependences(ProcName As String, ProjectName As String, PutativeDependences, Optional allreadyincluded = Nothing)


compcode = GetProcCode(ProcName, ProjectName) '
residue = Array("=", """", "-", "+", ";", "(", ")", "&", " ", ",", vbTab, vbCr, vbLf, ".")
compcode = MassReplace(compcode, "+", residue)
Do
i0 = Len(compcode)
compcode = Replace(compcode, "++", "+")
Loop While i0 <> Len(compcode)
tokens = tokenizer(compcode, False, "+", allreadyincluded)
Dim temparis()
For Each item In tokens
If ArrayContains(item, PutativeDependences, "bool") And Not ArrayContains(item, allreadyincluded) Then
Call AddToArrayListIfUnique(item, temparis)
End If
Next

[...]

allreadyincluded = ArrayConcatenate(allreadyincluded, temparis)

For Each item In temparis
Call FindProcDependences(CStr(item), ProjectName, PutativeDependences, allreadyincluded)  'Recursive calls
Next

End Sub
```

5.

```
Public Function GetProcCode(ProcName As String, Optional ProjectName As String = "")
Dim objComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim objCode As VBIDE.CodeModule
Set objComponent = FindComponentContainsProc(ProcName, ProjectName)
Set objCode = objComponent.CodeModule
iLine = objComponent.CodeModule.ProcStartLine(ProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
pclc = objCode.ProcCountLines(ProcName, pk)
GetProcCode = objCode.Lines(iLine, pclc)
Set objComponent = Nothing
Set objCode = Nothing
End Function
```

6.

```
Function FindComponentContainsProc(ProcName As String, Optional ProjectName As String = "", Optional ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind = vbext_pk_Proc) As VBIDE.VBComponent
[...]
Dim objComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent
For Each objComponent In objProject.VBComponents
pupProcLine = 0
Dim objCode As VBIDE.CodeModule
Set objCode = objComponent.CodeModule
On Error Resume Next
pupProcLine = objCode.ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind)
If pupProcLine > 0 Then Exit For
Next
[...]
End Function
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll see if I can use any of these. I'm pretty sure I won't be able to solve it completely (as shown in my accepted answer), but this may point me in the right direction/speed things up. Appreciate it!

Comment: The most important question is If you really need it as you mention that can also ... satisfy similar needs in other projects.  If you not paid for this I am not sure that worths the effort.